# Why does the logical OR operator in switch cases behave strangely?

Tags: javascript

The `testMyNumber` function seems to think numbers in the second position do not match.

Why do 4 and 10 return the default case?

```js
function testMyNumber(number) {
  switch (number) {
    case 6:
      return number+" is 6";
      break;
    case (3 || 4) :
      return number+" is 3 or 4";
      break;

    case 9 || 10 :
      return number+" is 9 or 10";
      break;

    default:
      return number+" is not in 3,4,6,9,10";
      break;
  }
};
console.log(testMyNumber(6));
console.log(testMyNumber(3));
console.log(testMyNumber(4));
console.log(testMyNumber(9));
console.log(testMyNumber(10));
```

Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because it wasn't intended to be used this way.

`||` returns its first operand if it's truthy, else its second operand.

`3 || 4` returns `3` because `3` is truthy, therefore `case` will check only `3`:

```js
console.log(3 || 4); //3, because it is truthy
console.log(0 || 1); //1, because 0 is falsy
```

To make your code work, use separate cases that fall through:

```js
function testMyNumber(number) {
  switch (number) {
    case 6:
      return number+" is 6";
    case 3:
    case 4:
      return number+" is 3 or 4";

    case 9:
    case 10:
      return number+" is 9 or 10";
    default:
      return number+" is not in 3,4,6,9,10";
  }
};
console.log(testMyNumber(6));
console.log(testMyNumber(3));
console.log(testMyNumber(4));
console.log(testMyNumber(9));
console.log(testMyNumber(10));
```

Comment: `break;` after `return ...;` isn't necessary either.

Comment: @Jesper I know, I've focused on fixing the problem in the code... Thanks anyway

Answer (score 9):

> Why 4 returns default case?

Because `(3 || 4)` is equal to `3`, so `case (3 || 4):` is the same as writing `case 3:`.

You are using incorrect syntax. Write it like this:

```
case 3:
case 4:
    return number + " is 3 or 4";
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `(3 || 4)` is `3` and its not 4, so it jumps to default.

```js
console.log((3 || 4));

var test = 4;

switch(test){
   case 3:
   case 4:
      console.log("3 and 4");
      break;
   default:
      console.log("default");
}
```

Write that cases underneath

Answer (score 3):

The reason is in two parts.

First of all, switch statements in JS cannot handle multiple values in a single case.

So what happens when you try to do so? Well see below.

```js
console.log(3 || 4);
```

Now why does `3 || 4` evaluate to `3`. To understand this, think about the OR operator with booleans.

`bool_a || bool_b`. If the `bool_a` is `true`, then the expression evaluates to `true`, think of this as evaluating to `bool_a`. If the value is `false` it will essentially return `bool_b`.

In Javascript this is exactly how things work. Just replace `true` and `false` with truthy and falsy.

```js
console.log(0 || 2);
console.log([]|| 2);
console.log(''|| 2);
console.log(false|| 2);

console.log("aaa" || 2);
console.log(true || 2);
```

To do this the way you want

```
case 3:
case 4:
    return number + " is 3 or 4"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do 3 || 4 the answer is 3.

The correct way to do this is like this

```js
function testMyNumber(number) {
  switch (number) {
    case 6:
      return number+" is 6";
      break;
    case 3:
    case 4:
      return number+" is 3 or 4";
      break;

    case 9:
    case 10 :
      return number+" is 9 or 10";
      break;

    default:
      return number+" is not in 3,4,6,9,10";
      break;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of the way the syntax works in JavaScript, **your `case 4:` is never defined**.

When you say `case (3 || 4):`, you're telling JavaScript the name for just one case, the case of **whatever your expression evaluates to**. In this example, `(3 || 4)` evaluates to `3`, so you're telling JavaScript `case 3:`.

The first code sample [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) shows what you are trying to do

Answer (score 1):

`case (3 || 4)` always evaluates to `3` because `3` is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

You could instead use multiple cases:

```js
function testMyNumber(number) {
  switch (number) {
    case 6:
      return number+" is 6";
      break;
    case 3:
    case 4:
      return number+" is 3 or 4";
      break;
    case 9:
    case 10:
      return number+" is 9 or 10";
      break;
    default:
      return number+" is not in 3,4,6,9,10";
      break;
  }
};

console.log(testMyNumber(6));
console.log(testMyNumber(3));
console.log(testMyNumber(4));
console.log(testMyNumber(9));
console.log(testMyNumber(10));
```

See the [MDN `switch` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).